# How to integrate Jmeter scripts with UFT or QTP

Tags: plugins, jmeter, qtp, uft-api

I want to run Jmeter script from UFT/QTP. Please let me know the if I need to install plugin for Jmeter in UFT and required setup for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate which direction? UFT is Unified **Functional** Testing and JMeter is a load testing tool which falls into [Non-Functional Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_testing) so there is no straightforward integration, you will have to use underlying operating system as a proxy.

- You can run QTP/UFT scripts from JMeter using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) and [CScript.exe](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/what-is-cscriptexe/b797cde9-4cda-4a51-862d-062b6adccc87?auth=1)
- You can run JMeter tests from QTP/UFT script like:

  ```
  Dim myCmd 
  Set myCmd = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell") 
  myCmd.run "cmd /c jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl" 
  Set myCmd = Nothing
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Integration at all? If you want to keep your environment clean you should not mix 2 different tools and technologies that have nothing to do with each other.

Let your CI System (Jenkins, HPE ALM / Octane etc) trigger the execution of the different types of tests. In case you have full UFT licenses then you may think about API Tests (Based on C# / .NET) and Load Tests based on HPE toolsuite.